# npm get WARN during install Sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

after i use `npm install sass` in cmd
then cmd show these errors

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\package.json'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\package.json'
npm WARN me No description
npm WARN me No repository field.
npm WARN me No README data
npm WARN me No license field.
+ sass@1.32.8
added 15 packages from 18 contributors and audited 16 packages in 3.402s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

i dont know how to solve these errors

Answer (score 0):

Those are just npm warnings about the package you are installing, in your case you don't have to worry about them unless something is not working. You can ignore them if you like by running:

```
npm install sass --silent
```

[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config)

Comment: thank you. but when these warnings occur, makes prevent realtime compiling sass to css( i use `--watch` ).